# Non-latching GPIO output that needs to disregard input

Tags: python, gpio, raspberry-pi-zero

New to programming, so I'll try my best to explain:

I'm trying to use a Pi Zero in my solar setup to switch the power-on input on an x86 motherboard (basically operating as the power button). The idea is that a battery voltage monitor sets pin 14 on the Pi high when the battery is at a high enough voltage. The script reads this input then switches an output (26) on the Pi, which in turn closes a relay for one second, which will then activate the power-on input on the motherboard.
The problem is that I cannot get the output (26) to turn off after one second. The script won't ignore pin 14, and just keeps the output (26) high. (Pin 14 is naturally held high by the battery monitor until the battery level falls down below a certain threshold)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(26, 1)

while True:
        if GPIO.input(14)==1:
                GPIO.output(26, 0)
                sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(26, 1)
        else:
                GPIO.output(26, 1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You only want to activate the relay when pin 14 *transitions* from low to high...so you need to track this situation so that you can compare the current value of GPIO14 to the previous value, and make an appropriate decision.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution that polls the value of GPIO14 1/second
and uses the variable `power_on` to figure out how we respond to the
value:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(26, 1)

power_on = False
while True:
    if not power_on:
        if GPIO.input(14) == 1:
                GPIO.output(26, 0)
                sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(26, 1)
                power_on = True
    else:
        if GPIO.input(14) == 0:
            power_off = True

    time.sleep(1)

# Note that you're never going to reach this line.
GPIO.cleanup()
```

---

Alternatively, you can have your code block until pin 14 changes, leading to something like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(26, 1)

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(14, GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.output(26, 0)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(26, 1)

# Note that you're never going to reach this line.
GPIO.cleanup()
```

This uses `GPIO.wait_for_edge()` to wait for a rising edge on GPIO14 (a low ➡️ high transition), and then triggers your relay.

Comment: Thank @larsks. I'll give that a try.

Comment: You're a genius larsks, thank you. The second one worked the best.
Now I just have to integrate the rest of the functionality.